# Multiple users on Samsung Galaxy A10

Tags: samsung

I want to be able to have two separate logins on my Galaxy A10 android phone, which require different passwords to access. Is this possible?

Comment: See if this works. https://www.phonetipsandtricks.com/tips/samsung-galaxy-a10/how-to-use-guest-mode-187/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Samsung added that feature in your rom, but this thing are provided as features from manufacturers. If your device lacks this feature, wait till new update.

Or you can install new rom for your device which have this feature. But it is risky as rooting and flashing new software involves.

Comment: It is unlikely an update would ever introduce multi user functionality. A multi user system requires reasonable amount of RAM (2GB in A10 is not gonna cut it).